# iPhone - Automate Appstore submission

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ruby, shell, scripting

Did anyone try scripting/Automating an Appstore app submission?

It will be amazing if we can save all the necessary info in a plist or a server, Click on one button to generate and Upload the App to iTunes connect.

This will be very useful if we have to develop template based Apps.

Any expert opinions/comments/samples?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I'm allowed to say the specifics (as it is under NDA right now), but if you're a registered developer the latest xcode kinda has this sort of thing (as I said, no more detail than that).

Comment: Thanks for the response the_great_monkey.
I am a registered user.
I guess with Xcode I can only generate Appstore builds, which I need to zip and upload manually to AppStore. What I am trying is - complete automation of the upload process. Unfortunately I can't find any apple api's to do this. If anyone has tried something like this... please post it here.

Comment: I'm not completely sure about what you mean by complete automation, but if you use the "build and archive" command in the new Xcode, you can actually submit the app from inside xcode by using the "submit app" button. Look at some WWDC 2010 videos from iTunes about xcode.